# What is the difference between keytool command's import and -importcert

Tags: java, security, keytool

I was told to add a certificate (.crt format) to the keystore file using keytool command. What option need to be used here, import or -importcert. When is each one used?

Comment: [keytool unix](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html)/[keytool windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) has no "import" command.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin : both links say  "This command was named -import in earlier releases. This old name is still supported in this release. The new name, -importcert, is preferred going forward."

Comment: @OlegEstekhin we use JDK 5

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From this documentation [keytool - Key and Certificate Management Tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html), the **Changes** section at the end of the page says :

> Renamed commands:
>
> -import, renamed to -importcert

So they basically are the same, and despite being renamed, `-import` *should* still exist later :

> All previous commands (both renamed and obsolete) are still supported
> in this release and will continue to be supported in future releases.

Note that this is from the Java SE 7 documentation, but the one from Java SE 8 ([unix](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html)/[windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html)) also says :

> This command was named -import in earlier releases. This old name is
> still supported in this release. The new name, -importcert, is
> preferred going forward.